# error occur while install git cmd

Tags: apt, dpkg, sudo, dependencies, git

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-mutter-10 : Depends: libmutter-10-0 (= 42.5-0ubuntu1) but 42.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (> 1:2.34.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (< 1:2.34.1-.) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Did you run the suggested command (`sudo apt --fix-broken install`)? If so, were there additional errors? If so, could you [edit] your question to include the version of Ubuntu you’re using and the full error messages? 

Comment: S I have run that cmd now the problem solved

Comment: So what did you learn from that? 